# Phonegap is installed using terminal but not working

Tags: node.js, cordova, cordova-3

I am working on phone gap camera plugin but i am facing the issues during installation of phone gap in mac

I install the NODE.JS as a recommended way then i run the command to install phonegap

```
sudo npm install -g phonegap
```

it is successfully installed but when i type "phonegap"

```
Thes-Mac-mini:application EngineerZ$ phonegap
-bash: phonegap: command not found
```

Please let me know if you understand my question.

Comment: try using cordova instead of phonegap

Comment: but i have same problem using cordova

Comment: uninstall phonegap and a start a fresh with this command npm install -g cordova